# Subcategory as % of category

Tags: powerbi

I have the following issue.

I'm trying to establish what % of a category is a subcategory.

Right now when dropping my values into a matrix it shows me what % of total a subcategory is in % of Total column. What I'm trying to establish is the % of Part column.

The Main issue I'm having is that the [Code qty] and [%of Total] are results of a measure, these are not columns in the power query.

I've tried the following measure but id did not work

```
DIVIDE(
CALCULATE('Report'[Code qty],
ALLEXCEPT(Codes_lookup,Codes_lookup[Code])),
CALCULATE([Code qty],ALLEXCEPT(Part_Lookup,Part_Lookup[part_number])))
```

Please see below example how my matrix looks (I've had to move it to excel as the original matrix holds customer-sensitive info)

[image]

Could anyone support on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following measure:

```
% of Part = 
VAR __a = IF( ISBLANK( [Code qty]), BLANK(), CALCULATE([Code qty], ALLSELECTED(Codes_lookup[Code]) ) )
VAR __b = [Code qty]
    
VAR div = DIVIDE(__b, __a, 0 )
Return div
```

I got the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Works like a dream, thanks very much for your support.